# Issue in Joins when some fields are null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get exactly one row with `car` data with the `carName` and the values, if they exist, for this car's `makerName` and `plateNumber`.

For example `Ford Taurus, Ford, 4AD843`.

If for some reason the `Ford Taurus` doesn't have a plate number, I want to get this one row with no value in the plate number column, for example

```
Ford Taurus, Ford, null.
```

I tried the `sql` below but I get all the values for all the `maker` and `license` tables, and if I add to the `where` clause the constraint for `car.id` in the `maker` and `license` tables I get 0 rows if the value in `license` is `null`.

So how can this be done?

What I tried:

```
select 
    car.id as carID,
    maker.carId as makerCarId, maker.name as makerName, 
    license.carId as licenseCarId, license.plateNumber as plateNumber 
from 
    car car,
    maker maker, 
    license license  
    where car.id = 4951
;
```

Comment: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Where are the conditions for joining the tables. You get a cross product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SQL [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) keyword, that returns all rows from the left table (`car`), with the matching rows in the right table (`maker` or `license`). The result is `NULL` in the right side when there is no match.

```
SELECT car.id AS carID
    , maker.name AS makerName
    , license.plateNumber AS plateNumber 
FROM car AS car
LEFT JOIN maker AS maker ON car.id = maker.carId
LEFT JOIN license AS license ON car.id = license.carId
WHERE car.id = 4951
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for a `left join`:

```
SELECT
    car.id AS carID,
    maker.carId AS makerCarId, maker.name AS makerName, 
    license.carId AS licenseCarId, license.plateNumber AS plateNumber 
FROM
    car
JOIN
    maker ON car.id = maker.carId
LEFT JOIN
    license ON car.id = license.carId 
where car.id = 4951
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of your query is a cartesian join between tables car, maker and license.
This will result in all the rows having the car id provided in the `WHERE` clause.

For your expected result, you need to refine the result set using the filter or join condition between the tables used in the query.

Use the below query for your expected result:

`SELECT car.id AS carID
    , maker.name AS makerName
    , license.plateNumber AS plateNumber 
FROM car AS car
JOIN maker AS maker ON car.id = maker.carId
LEFT OUTER JOIN license AS license ON car.id = license.carId
WHERE car.id = 4951;e`

I've added `OUTER JOIN` in condition to get the desired result even if there is no license plate. Using only `JOIN` condition will not fetch the desired result if there is no license plate number for the car.